# How to draw samples from a multivariate Gaussian in Lua/Torch

Tags: lua, normal-distribution, torch

I turns out Torch does not have any built-in function for drawing samples for a multivariate Gaussian distribution given a desired covariance matrix. Can anyone tell me how I can draw samples from a multivariate Gaussian distribution using a desired covariance matrix?

Here's my try:

I installed the `randomkit` package from [here](https://github.com/deepmind/torch-randomkit) using `luarocks install randomkit` in terminal. However, when I do `require 'randomkit'` in Lua I cannot find the `multivariate_normal` function as one of the elements of `randomkit`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [torch-distributions](https://github.com/deepmind/torch-distributions/blob/master/doc/src/index.markdown) package. To install it, run the following command in terminal:

```
luarocks install https://raw.github.com/jucor/torch-distributions/master/distributions-0-0.rockspec
```

Below is a working example in lua to draw samples from a multivariate normal distribution:

```
require 'distributions'
mu = torch.Tensor({10, 0})
sigma = torch.eye(2)
sample = distributions.mvn.rnd(mu, sigma) -- a sample from the distribution
```

Comment: It does not work to me... is it still working to you? Did they change something in the package? Thanks

Comment: You need to `require 'distributions'` as well. I will update my answer.